# Using Charge plugin with Stripe Connect

Tags: plugin-charge, stripe

Has anyone set up the Charge plugin with Stripe Connect? I've followed the docs and things look good in the Craft back-end but the payments don't look to be routed to the correct Stripe accounts on the Stripe end.

The Squarebit docs refer to a config setting which I need but I haven't been able to track this down.

https://squarebit.co.uk/software/craft/charge/usage/controllers/connect-controller

Comment: Have you contacted Square Bit, as directed in the docs?

Comment: Yes Ive tried that...

Answer (score 1):

Developer of Charge here.

The full details on the setup for Connect are detailed here : https://squarebit.co.uk/software/craft/charge/usage/reference/connect-setup

Setting up a Charge to use Connect takes 4 broad steps -

1. Configuring your Stripe Account, and Charge settings - this involves putting your platform keys into Charge, and the callback url(s) in to the Stripe settings
2. Adding the Charge Connect field to the elements you want to use as the parent elements for the connected accounts.
3. Updating your templates to reference these connected fields.
4. Actually connecting accounts to use - using the field you created in step 2.

From the sounds of it - the issue you're having is in either step 3, or 4.

The first thing to look in is the Charge > Logs - which will detail exactly what's happening, and why things aren't going to the connected accounts. It's almost certainly due to either the proper information isn't being passed through on the request (ie. a template issue) or an account issue (ie. the connected accounts aren't in the appropriate mode to accept payments)

Comment: Thanks for the response Joel. I believe I have followed the steps correctly – I have configured the Stripe account and set things up on the Charge end as specified in the docs. 

I have connected the account and Im seeing that on the Stripe end. 

When I process the payment Im not seeing that come through on Stripe - the payment is added to the main Stripe account and does not appear in the Connect view.

It looks right in Charge. One thing Im seeing in the log is 'API Excpetion when finding customer' but the Charge is listed a successfully completed.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'the connected accounts aren't in the appropriate mode to accept payments'?

Comment: Hi @jJoel Bradbury, Are you still working on this plugin.As one of my client site is using your plugin, and we are planning to update it for SCA.